# Create a loop over a function that prints out the elements the function it takes in, in a new row using a wrapper

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that takes two lists. Now what I have right now is that the function will take all of the parameters from the list and print them in a new row. The problem is that I can't change the function itself but instead I would have to create a wrapper over it or a loop to do what I need it to do.

```
Name = ['one', 'two', 'three']
size = [1, 2, 3]

def createSomething(Name, size = None):
    if size:
         something = loudEchoCmd("something create --size %s --name %s " % ((',')join(size), (',')join(Name)))
    else:
         something = loudEchoCmd("something create --name %s " % (',')join(Name))
    return something
```

What I get when I run this is:

```
 Example:
 something create --size 1, 2, 3 --name one, two, three
```

This is what I want to get:

```
 Example:
 something create --size 1 --name one
 something create --size 2 --name two
 something create --size 3 --name three
```

So I need to create a wrapper over that function that does what I need it to do. I have no idea how to do this. This is how I would get it to do by just changing the function:

```
  def createSomething(Name, size = None):
      if size:
         for(i, (x1, x2)) in enumerate(zip(size,Name)):
             loudEchoCMD("something create --size {0} --name {1}")
      else:
         for x in Name:
             loudEchoCMD("something create --name {0}".format(x))
```

But no idea how to do it without changing the function :(

Comment: What's to stop you creating a new function?

Comment: I suggested creating a new function that just did this but was told it would be simpler to just create a wrapper. Which as it turns out (at least to me) is not simpler. So now I come to you fine folks and ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
def createManySomethings(Names, sizes):
    for (name, number) in zip(Names, sizes):
        createSomething([name], [number])
```

Comment: Note that when you call createSomething, it expects two lists.  If you pass it lists containing only one item each, the function does what you'd like.

Comment: Yeah when I have one Item each I get what I want but I have lists with more than one item which is where the problem arises. What do name and number stand for?

Comment: This works for me thank you. Name and number are just x1, x2 if I had created a new function.